# how to make a tableview to be grouped style without indenting cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios

I want a tableview without floating headers and footers, but in the UITableViewStylePlain style. When I used a grouped style tableview, it draws this rounded rectangle around my cells, and it is annoying!! Is there a setting to turn this off?

I have tried

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

All don't work. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Was there a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cells background colors. The white rounded rectangle you see is a result of the cells - not the tableView (a little confusing).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Standard Cell Setup in cellForRowAtINdexPath method

     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Also you can change the color of the separators to whatever you want:

```
    theTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Comment: hmm, this doenst acheive what I need, because I would like my cells to have alternating colors. Furthermore, I need them to go to the edge of the table, not floating with some 'padding' on either side.

Comment: That's not the Apple recommended way to change the background colour of a table cell. See UITableViewCell doc's Overview section: "Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property declared by UIView) you must do it in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source [...]"